# How can I add my developer account to Xcode using Script from GitHub Actions?

Tags: ios, xcode, github-actions

I was trying to automate CI-Cd process using Github Actions. However facing issues related to

> "There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer
> account to Xcode".

Can someone please assist me how this can be resolved using the script. I was using the self hosted macOS runner.